# Gitlab configuration with custom port isn't able to call pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I m trying to configure gitlab behind a reverse proxy and I m facing some troubles even before configuring the reverse proxy service itself.

First, I'm using Gitlab 8.13

**What I had working**

I've configured a gitlab server on port 80, managing my projects, possibility to build with embedded pipeline ci. The only configuration I've modified was :

```
external_url 'http://custom-ip'
```

I also had a runner configured this way :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "project-front"
  url = "http://customIp/gitlab/ci"
  token = "secretToken"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:6"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
```

All worked in a perfect world.

**What I've now, that doesn't work**

I'm trying to switch gitlab port to run somewhere else, and to me the :80 port for another service (the reverse proxy). For testing environnement, I have the 9999 port temporarily opened to access my gitlab service.

I tried by modifying my external_url this way :

```
external_url 'http://customIp:9999/gitlab'
```

And changed my runner configuration to :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "project-front"
  url = "http://127.0.0.1:9999/gitlab/gitlab/ci"
  token = "secretToken"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:6"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
```

It works when I navigate in the gitlab UI.

*The problem*

The problem appears when I try to start a build with pipeline. When I try to start a new build, I've the loading information for some minutes(~10mns for a build that takes, maximum 2 mns, so I stopped it) :

[image]

*NB : The fact that I've got 2x /gitlab in the url is due to the external_url conf that I've set, and the default /gitlab/ci path that the gitlab server uses internally*

**Questions**

How can I set my configurations so that my builds will continue working on my gitlab server set on port 9999 instead of 80 ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that port number (and anything after the colon in hostname/IP address) is stripped in gitlab-ci-multi-runner

Related to this?:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/merge_requests/375

Also seems to fail to use port as given during:

`docker exec -it <<container name>> gitlab-runner register`

**Update**: got it working based on an issue resolved a year ago - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1551